# How to resolve app uninstall without adhoc

Tags: applications, xcode, ios

When I installed the app with help of this [link](http://www.securitylearn.net/2012/12/26/build-ipa-file-using-xcode-without-provisioning-profile/) onto my device but this procedure has problems under iOS 7 which i have reported to apple but i'm wondering if someone knows of a fix in the mean time?

When you click the link to install, the app installing icons appears and after a short time a second icon appears with the proper app icon but the install one does not disappear (see image below) even if i delete the app the installing icon stays. Any ideas on how to fix this would be much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Is your phone jailbroken?

Comment: no and My iphone Model is 5s @patrix

Comment: Thanks. but i need how to uninstall that app on my device

Comment: Oops, sorry, misread the question. Reboot didn't help?

Comment: yes friend i made more then 3 times but didn't help @patrix

Answer (score 1):

A few suggestions:

> 1. Load a earlier Backup from the iCloud and "restore" it to this state
> 2. Log Out of your Apple Account and reboot.
> 3. Connect your iPhone via cable with your PC/Mac and sync your apps

Comment: i'm get new iPhone before one week still i never get backup before